# Moq doesn't match methods. Moq.MockException: All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

Moq doesn't match the mocked method.

Exception:

> Exception thrown: 'Moq.MockException' in Moq.dll:
> 'IMongoRepository.FindByVrcId("b4cb3139-90aa-4477-979b-d893e3317386")
> invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the
> mock must have a corresponding setup.'

This is my unit test:

```cs
public class OfferHandlerTest : TestBase
{
    Mock<IMongoRepository> repositoryMock = new Mock<IMongoRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    OfferHandler? offerHandler;

    [Fact]
    public void HandleTest()
    {
        JObject? offerFullDocument = null;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader("Data/offer_full_document.json"))
        {
            var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
            offerFullDocument = JObject.Load(reader);
        }

        var kafkaPayload = new KafkaMessagePayloadSourceConnector();
        kafkaPayload.OperationType = Constants.Mongo_OperationType_Update;
        kafkaPayload.FullDocument = offerFullDocument;

        OfferService service = new OfferService(repositoryMock.Object);
        offerHandler = new OfferHandler(service, this.ServiceConfiguration);

        offerHandler.Handle(kafkaPayload);

        DHOffer offer = new DHOffer();
        offer.Version = 1;

        // THIS SETUP FAILS
        repositoryMock.Setup(s => s.FindByVrcId<DHOffer>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(It.IsAny<DHOffer>());

        repositoryMock.Verify(s => s.FindAndUpdate<DHOffer>(It.IsAny<DHOffer>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

This is the handle method:

```cs
public void Handle(KafkaMessagePayloadSourceConnector kafkaPayload)
{
    VRCOffer offer = kafkaPayload!.FullDocument!.ToObject<VRCOffer>()!;

    if (kafkaPayload!.OperationType!.Equals(Constants.Mongo_OperationType_Update))
    {
        offerService.updateOfferStatus(OfferMapper.MapToDataHubModel(offer), offer.MasterId);
    }
}
```

And finally the service method:

```cs
public class OfferService
{
    private readonly IMongoRepository offerRepository;

    public OfferService(IMongoRepository offerRepository)
    {
        this.offerRepository = offerRepository;
    }
    
    internal void updateOfferStatus(DHOffer offer, string vrcMasterId)
    {
        // THIS SHOULD RETURN MOCKED OBJECT
        DHOffer existingOffer = offerRepository.FindByVrcId<DHOffer>(vrcMasterId);
        existingOffer.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        existingOffer.AdditionalInformation.Status = offer?.AdditionalInformation?.Status!;

        offerRepository.FindAndUpdate(existingOffer);
    }
}
```

I tried using `It.IsAny<DHOffer>()` in the `Return()` method but I get the same exception.

Comment: You shouldn't use `It.IsAny` in the return, make a new `DHOffer` object. The rest of your code looks mostly fine though. Do you really have the `.Setup` at the bottom? That should be done before the object is used. Put if before the `OfferService service = new...` line.

Comment: You can't Verify an invocation that wasn't Setup; you setup one method but verify another.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon You are correct, but that won't cause the exception being shown here.

Comment: 'All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.' FindAndUpdate is an invocation of your mock so @MathieuGuindon should be right

Comment: @DavidG yup, that was the issue, "Do you really have the .Setup at the bottom?" yes really. lol @MathieuGuindon  Yes I also had to add the `repositoryMock.Setup(s => s.FindAndUpdate<DHOffer>(It.IsAny<DHOffer>())).Verifiable();` before calling Handle() method.

Comment: Does anyone want to post the answer or should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are running the Moq setup *after* the mocked object has been used. By then it's already too late. You just need to run the `.Setup(...)` commands at the start.

It's also worth noting that using a shared mock can be problematic if multiple tests need the setups to be different. Some tools can run tests in parallel which may screw things up, or in a different order which can cause things to be more brittle.

Comment: regarding shared mock, this class only has one test, and its probably not going to change I will consider this if I add more test methods.